# Is there a way to set a default home/launcher programatically on Android?

Tags: android, default, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I've created my own home/launcher and would like to set it as default depending on my location, but as far as I'm aware you can only clear/set defaults for home in the 'settings->applications->manage applications->*name of home/launcher*' : is this possible? I'm guessing it's not as it kind of takes control away from the user but I thought I would check...

Comment: I have also face this problem, how to can I set launcher as default launcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to set a default HOME application from code, if you could do it it would be a security issue.

Comment: see go launcher app, in that application they do, after installing app it's launcher directly appear, no need choose GO Launcher after installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: But it is not possible to specify the specific page.

Comment: This will launch a particular home app, but the 'home' button itself will still launch whichever home is set as default...

Answer (score 0):

We analyse an app named Launcher Switcher, it seems run ok in Android 2.2.  Click a button to set the default launcher. But I installed it in Android 4.0, it's not work. After set the default launcher, when click the HOME button, the launcher choice window is still opens.

referenced from this:
[Set default Home app dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980899/set-default-home-app-dynamically)